# React Native release apk crashes on launch after update to Android 13 (API level 33)

Tags: android, react-native

I have upgraded the API level of my existing react native code to 33. Here is the buildscript body in android -> build.gradle,

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        androidXCore = "1.6.0"

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine if I run it from Android Studio on the emulator. But as soon as I make an apk, the app crashes with the following error,

[image: error after launching release apk]

Comment: If you resolved the errors plz Aprove my answer also for the better understand of SC.